# Help for a Gentile in quoting Tanach

Tags: tanach, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

My daughter has a friend, Abigail, who is about to have her Bat Mitzvah, which unfortunately she can't attend. We wanted to make a gift for her that would make her feel special on this important day in her life. We are not Jewish, though I have some faculty with Hebrew, and my daughter is a fabulous artist. So we planned to give her a hand drawn portrait, and underneath put the words from, what I would know as, First Samuel 25:3

> אֲבִגָיִל וְהָאִשָּׁה טוֹבַת־שֶׂכֶל וִיפַת תֹּאַר "Abigail was of good understanding and a beautiful countenance."

I have two concerns: first of all is this an appropriate gift? And secondly, I'm not sure how to cite this verse in a Hebrew context rather than the modern English Bible's use of 1Sam 25:3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: והאשה is syntactically awkward. Maybe omit it or replace with ellipses?

Comment: The Jewish numbering is the same as the Christian, largely because we copied it from them. We'd call it Shmuel Aleph rather than One Samuel.

Comment: The citation is Shmuel Aleph, 25:3 in english or שמואל א (כה,ג) in Hebrew. As for if it's an appropriate gift, it's certainly very thoughtful; I'm sure nobody will take issue with it.